# Return rows with different specific data for the same column or return 0 rows using POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am in college learning SQL vis Postgresql.
This is my first post here so if I'm not posting correctly, let me know.
I have a question that has me stumped.

A bank setup with multiple users having multiple accounts at multiple branches in multiple cities.
The question wants to find any users that have at least 1 account at every branch in a specific city.

There are 3 branches in Brooklyn. I need to find all user ID's that have at least one account in each branch.

If they do not have at least 1 account in each branch, it should not return anything for that user.

I don't know how to return multiple rows with different results from the same column and REQUIRE the specific branch names be present or return nothing at all.
(userID = a on one row, b on another row, c on anther row or do not return userID at all.)
I do not want the entire answer, I just need to know what function I can use to do this and maybe some general guidance on what to do.

I can provide the table information if needed.

Thank you.

Comment: I can provide the table information if needed. :-) and bettre here http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Ok that's pretty cool. Again, I don't want the complete answer, just an over view.
Here's my link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1e193b/1

Comment: Good job! I need to find all user ID's that have at least one account in each branch. ... To well understand, what are the tables concerned? I don't see user_id

Comment: Did you see my sql in the fiddle, you need to have a table that links accoun_number to user_id/customerçid ...

Comment: Sorry, it's just ID not userID. Customer table has ID and links to depositor table. Depositor table has account_number which leads to the account table, which has the branch_name which leads to the branch table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want the complete answer

Good and better to learn.

So I explain here how to do , just let me know what's not clear.

I need to find all user ID's that have at least one account in each branch.

We construst the sql in 3 times :

sql1 : per City the name of branches

sql2 :  per ID & City the name of branches

sql3 : ID from sql1 & sql2 whith same branches

Go ahead and ask when you need.

On clue is to be able to have one field with all the branches in order to be able to test it easily.

See the logic in comment and other answer to get the final solution.

Comment: So I need a query that groups the branch_name by city and a second query that groups the branch_name by ID and City and then join or union them?

Comment: Not UNION that is to add rows, a simple JOIN of 2 subqueires and 1 WHERE. Begin by creating the 2 firsts and share them (on the fiddle)

Comment: Not UNION that is to add rows, a JOIN from your 2 subqueries with a WHERE. Begin by wirting the 2 first and share them (on the fiddle)

Comment: 2 comments 1) Why choose only 1 city 'Brooklyn', best is to do the sql for all the cities 2) more 'difficult', if you/we want to use a where in the main query, we must have only one row per city/(id) ... that means "regroup" all the branches ... do you know how?

Comment: Should I only return the branch_name in each query and group them?

Comment: Try for the first one and let me know

Comment: SQLFiddle stopped working for me. Says couldn't acquire connection from underlying database. I will post the first one as soon it works again.

Comment: Same think for me for an other one, probably too mny users at this time ...

Comment: we can try on chat if you want ... but I never used it before I am still newbie on so :-)

Comment: Ok, it's working again for me, but I'm not sure I understand what I am supposed to do now.  I removed the where clause that specified 'Brooklyn'. Do I need to group by the city now?

Comment: Per city, elaborate an unique field that contains all the branches.

Comment: No, you have more the one line per city. You can do it by aggregate function array_agg, json or with array. We don't need the keys so no need to work with json. Try with array_agg. select city, array_agg(branch) as branches from ... group by city ...

Comment: I live in eu and have to go to bed. We can continue tomorrow if you want. Try array_agg, it should not difficult on 2 sql but remember that we have to compare at the end ... the branches must be ordered because A,B,C <> A,C,B

Comment: I believe I figured it out. This is what I came up with.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1e193b/29

I tested and it seems to work fine. Thank you.

Comment: Good job but the fiddle returns an error. Consider closing that post by making my answer on best and give the solution in a second answer, like this next reader will be able to see all the logic.

Comment: An error? That's odd. It seems to work fine for me. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Hi @Whovian This mornig, I was not able to open the fiddle (the fiddle sheet was in error), now it's ok , you do well and I thing you understand how to do. In postgresql you can also work with array but array does not exist in mysql since array_agg = group_concat in mysql so you are now to do the same thing in mysql too :-)